# Parse and charset: why my script doesn't work

Tags: rebol

I want to extract attribute1 and attribute3 values only. I don't understand why charset doesn't seem to work in my case to "skip" any other attributes (attribute3 is not extracted as I would like):

```
content: {<tag attribute1="valueattribute1" attribute2="valueattribute2" attribute3="valueattribute3">
</tag>
<tag attribute2="valueattribute21" attribute1="valueattribute11" >
</tag>
}


attribute1: [{attribute1="} copy valueattribute1 to {"} thru {"}]
attribute3: [{attribute3="} copy valueattribute3 to {"} thru {"}]

spacer: charset reduce [tab newline #" "]
letter: complement spacer 
to-space: [some letter | end]

attributes-rule: [(valueattribute1: none valueattribute3: none) [attribute1 | none] any letter [attribute3 | none] (print valueattribute1 print valueattribute3)
| [attribute3 | none] any letter [attribute1 | none] (print valueattribute3 print valueattribute1
valueattribute1: none valueattribute3: none
)
| none
]

rule: [any [to {<tag } thru {<tag } attributes-rule {>} to {</tag>} thru {</tag>}] to end]

parse content rule
```

output is

```
>> parse content rule
valueattribute1
none
== true
>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you're not using `parse/all`.  In Rebol 2 that means that whitespace has been effectively stripped out before the parse runs.  That's not true in Rebol 3: if your parse rules are in block format (as you are doing here) then `/all` is implied.

*(Note: There seemed to be consensus that Rebol 3 would [throw out the non-block form of parse rules](http://www.rebol.net/cgi-bin/r3blog.r?view=0266), in favor of the `split` function for those "minimal" parse scenarios.  That would get rid of `/all` entirely.  No action has yet been taken on this, unfortunately.)*

Secondly your code has bugs, which I'm not going to spend time sorting out.  (That's mostly because I think using Rebol's parse to process XML/HTML is a fairly silly idea :P)

But don't forget you have an important tool.  If you use a set-word in the parse rule, then that will capture the parse position into a variable.  You can then print it out and see where you're at.  Change the part of `attribute-rule` where you first say `any letter` to `pos: (print pos) any letter` and you'll see this:

```
>> parse/all content rule
 attribute2="valueattribute2" attribute3="valueattribute3">
</tag>
<tag attribute2="valueattribute21" attribute1="valueattribute11" >
</tag>

valueattribute1
none
== true
```

See the leading space?  Your rules right before the `any letter` put you at a space... and since you said any letter was ok, no letters are fine, and everything's thrown off.

*(Note: Rebol 3 has an even better debugging tool...the word `??`.  When you put it in the parse block it tells you what token/rule you're currently processing as well as the state of the input.  With this tool you can more easily find out what's going on:*

```
>> parse "hello world" ["hello" ?? space ?? "world"]
space: " world"
"world": "world"
== true
```

*...though it's really buggy on r3 mac intel right now.)*

Additionally, if you're not using `copy` then your pattern of `to X thru X` is unnecessary, you can achieve that with just `thru X`.  If you want to do a copy you can also do that with the briefer `copy Y to X X` or if it's just a single symbol you could write the clearer `copy Y to X skip`

In places where you see yourself writing repetitive code, remember that Rebol can go a step above by using `compose` etc:

```
>> temp: [thru (rejoin [{attribute} num {=}]) 
          copy (to-word rejoin [{valueattribute} num]) to {"} thru {"}]

>> num: 1
>> attribute1: compose temp
== [thru "attribute1=" copy valueattribute1 to {"} thru {"}]

>> num: 2
>> attribute2: compose temp
== [thru "attribute2=" copy valueattribute2 to {"} thru {"}]
```

Comment: >using Rebol's parse to process XML/HTML is a fairly silly idea

:) in truth it's for parsing ASP.NET C# code ... but maybe that's still silly !

Comment: But I can't see any other tool to parse ASP.NET code so I use Rebol :)

Comment: And I don't need to write a full blown parser, I just need to do simple extraction of some attributes.

Comment: forgot to say: an important requirement is that the rules should be human readable by layman, that's why I don't want full blown classical parser.

Comment: The problem is you're building in a lot of expectations to the code of things like the order of the attributes, which those developing XML and HTML oriented things are pretty liberal about changing because such order isn't supposed to carry meaning.  You might be able to hack something that works for one case, but if the code is intended to have a broader usefulness then it's best to stick with a real DOM-oriented parser.

Comment: You're right, I have to change my strategy : sometimes I nearly believe Rebol is not a programming language but a natural language that can mimic human thoughts not so in that case but I learnt more about parse in that way thanks to you :)

Comment: Finally I have thought to parse ALL attributes using parse and break but seems it won't work, can't see why break can't do this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457618/parse-and-break-why-break-cannot-be-used-for-getting-out-of-any-or-some-rule

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, [any letter] eats your attribute3="..." as the #"^"" character is by your definition a 'letter.  Additionally, you may have problems where there is no attribute2, then your generic second attribute rule will eat attribute3 and your attribute3 rule will not have anything to match - better to either be explicit that there is an optional attribute2 or an optional anything-but-attribute3

```
attribute1="foo"       attribute2="bar" attribute3="foobar" 
<- attribute1="..." -> <-     any letter                 -> <- attibute3="..." ->
```

Also, 'parse without the /all refinement ignores spaces (or at least is very unwieldy where spaces are concerned) - /all is highly recommended for this type of parsing.

Comment: And what if I have 10 optional attributes as my example is just a simplified case of I need in real world :) it would be cumbersome to be explicit as I would have to list all combinations of alternation of the 10 attributes !

Comment: Thanks for [any letter] eating and for #"^"" I didn't realize

Answer (score 0):

When adding parse/all it didn't seem to change anything. Finally this seems to work (using set-word has been indeed a great help for debugging !!!), what do you think ?

```
content: {<tag attribute1="valueattribute1" attribute2="valueattribute2" attribute3="valueattribute3">
</tag>
<tag attribute2="valueattribute21" attribute1="valueattribute11" >
</tag>
}


attribute1: [to {attribute1="} thru {attribute1="} copy valueattribute1 to {"} thru {"}]
attribute3: [to {attribute3="} thru {attribute3="} copy valueattribute3 to {"} thru {"}]

letter: charset reduce ["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890="]

attributes-rule: [(valueattribute1: none valueattribute3: none) 
[attribute1 | none] any letter pos: 
[attribute3 | none] (print valueattribute1 print valueattribute3)
| [attribute3 | none] any letter [attribute1 | none] (print valueattribute3 print valueattribute1
valueattribute1: none valueattribute3: none
)
| none
]

rule: [any [to {<tag } thru {<tag } attributes-rule {>} to {</tag>} thru {</tag>}] to end]

parse content rule
```

which outputs:

```
>> parse/all content rule
valueattribute1
valueattribute3
valueattribute11
none
== true
>>
```

Comment: Since you weren't aware of the "get parse position" trick with set-words, I'll mention the analogous tool for "set parse position" from a variable pointing to a series type... use a get-word!  Cool, huh?