# Parse and Break: why break cannot be used for getting out of "any" or "some" rule?

Tags: rebol

Let say I have to parse a hierarchical set of tags

```
<tag>
<subtag1 attr1=value1 attr2=value2>
<subtag1 attr1=value1 attr2=value2>
<subtag1 attr1=value1 attr2=value2>
</tag>
```

Why can't I use break inside some or any to get out of a level hierarchy ? This would allow to do that kind of parsing instead of having a headache to do so ?

I'm asking this because I read here http://www.codeconscious.com/rebol/parse-tutorial.html it would create an infinite loop

This case produces an infinite loop. Because the BREAK is within a sub-rule of the rule that SOME is processing. The BREAK does not affect success/failure status or the input pointer - it just exits a rule early:

> > rule-to-break: [(print "*Break*") break]
> >     == [(print "*Break*") break]
> >     parse "X" [some [rule-to-break] "X"]
> >     *Break*
> >     *Break*
> >     ...
> >     *Break*
> >     *Break*(escape)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That gives an infinite loop in Rebol 2, you are correct.  But remember that `parse` has undergone major upgrades and revisions in the most recent version, based on feedback of users.

So in Rebol 3, you get:

```
>> rule-to-break: [(print "Break") break] 
== [(print "Break") break]

>> parse "X" [some [rule-to-break] "X"]
Break
== true
```

Carl wrote a bit on the nuance of Rebol 3's break behavior on the R3 blog:

http://www.rebol.net/r3blogs/0277.html

- **fail**: explicitly fail a single rule, skip to the next alternative (if it has one).
- **break**: explicitly exit the entire rule block, skip all alternatives.
- **return**: explicitly exit all rules, return from the parse function.

Rebol 2 is kind of set in stone at this point; there's limits to how much work is going to be done to fix it.  You should test all your examples in Rebol 3.

Comment: I tried to install Rebol 3. At home it works, in the corporate client environment it doesn't.

So I tried something else and I'm hitting the wall once again:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463412/i-thought-this-parsing-would-be-simple